# Как залить готовый React проект на CMS? И какие CMS посоветуете?

Tags: reactjs, cms

У меня есть React приложение (собрана на create-react-app), а бэк на Node. Приложение представляет собой новостной сайт/блог. Нужен совет по CMS и ответ на некоторые вопросы:

1. Какой CMS для React лучше? (Присмотрелся к headless CMS-кам, например Strapi, но возможно и WP Rest API или что там еще...)
2. При выборе CMS, я должен переписать проект с нуля или могу поверх готового проета залить на CMS? (Повторюсь, проет написан на create-react-app)
3. Какие видео, источники, документации есть по данным CMS, отправьте на ваш выбор.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы собираетесь использовать CMS, то back вам не нужен. CMS, грубо говоря, back - end с визуальным редактором. Ну из всех CMS которые я знаю, я бы посоветовал вам Strapi, это одна из моих любимых CMS. Ну или как вариант можете обратить внимание на WordPress, там тоже вроде можно использовать API

Comment: Да, вы правы. Многие советуют Strapi для React-a. Спасбо за ответ!